# How can I stop Ubuntu linux trapping the CTRL-tab key combination?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> in an emacs application. But the Ubuntu 10 OS under GNOME traps this key combination. How can I disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the Gnome keybindings by running the program `gnome-keybinding-properties` from a terminal window (or alternately from the Gnome menu *System->Preferences->Keyboard Shortcuts*).